# How to rename an oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, rename

I am running Oracle 11g on windows 2003. What are the steps to rename database? I had followed the steps in http://www.ordba.net/Tutorials/OracleUtilities~DBNEWID.htm but I can't get past the error,

NID-00121: Database should not be open

I had tried the exact steps that were mentioned in the link but still it gives me the same error.

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Arther

Answer (score 1):

First, make a backup of the db.
Second, try this one:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RenamingOrMovingOracleFiles.php

Anyway renaming an oracle db is always complicated.
That error is because you try to rename the db when it's open.
As it's written there, you should:

shutdown immediate

startup mount